# How do I forward forward the request to other micro services

Tags: node.js, express, request, microservices

I have been worked on NodeJS for 5 years. My present assignment is to developing microservice in ExpressJS.

In the microservice architecture, we know that the gateway forwards the requests to the respective microservice received from the client. Right now my current application has 4 microservices.
- gateway
- authentication
- user
- product

The primary duty of gateway is to receive the request from the client and forward it to authentication microservice or other microservices. Recently I come across proxy npm express-http-proxy modules, and it has the same request forwarding feature.

I have 2 ways to forward the request to other microservices.

1. Use of simplified HTTP client that will redirect the request from a gateway to respective microservices. Here I have listed a few of them npm modules.

   - request
   - axios
   - got
2. Another way is to use a proxy package. I felt express-http-proxy is the most suitable to forward the request to other microservice. Few other npm modules are listed below.

   - express-http-proxy
   - http-proxy-middleware

In the past, I have used request and axios modules to forward the request to other microservices.

Today I have found that express-http-proxy is also the alternate of it. It also forwards the request to other microservice. But other modules (http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware, node-http-proxy) are more popular than express-http-proxy 
but they are not working as expected.

To forward the request is not only the context, but we also need to taking care of response or error that occurs from the microservice.

I am not able to decide that which is a more efficient, robust solution to forward the microservice?

Hope I explain my point of view.

Comment: I recommend considering https://www.express-gateway.io/

Express-Gateway has become moderately popular. https://www.express-gateway.io/ I believe that either by using them or looking at their source code and understanding their approach could help you.

Comment: @nirr I will definitely looking into that. Thank you for your response.